# Webmaster Tools Crawler 403 errors

Tags: http-status-code-403, googlebot, google-search-console

Google Webmaster Tools is reporting 403 errors for some folders on the websites server for example:

http://www.philaletheians.co.uk/Study%20notes/

The folder isnt forbidden so dont understand why it would be 403 errors for Googles Crawler?

How come the Google Crawler is trying to browser the actual folders and not just going straight to the files in that folder? Is this somthing to do with robots.txt ?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure is there any actual place or document to be present if some one request that url. I've browsed through your site and could not found a link that directs to http://www.philaletheians.co.uk/Study%20notes/
Also it seems, all the study notes are inside this "Study%20notes" directory.So actual this link will not work anyway. So check the google web master tools's link from to find where this broken link situate and cure it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you set default document correctly in your web server? In apache, this comes in the DirectoryIndex setting (and defaults to index.html). Also, in general it might be better to strip off spaces etc.. from your traversable directory names (the %20 you are seeing between Study and notes is a url-encoded space character), so as to keep your URLs clean to your visitors and search engine bots.